# How to compute the expectation of $\frac{Y^L}{Y^L + (N-Y)^L}$ where Y is Binomial(n,p)

Tags: pr.probability, approximation-theory

How to compute the expectation of  $\frac{Y^L}{Y^L + (N-Y)^L}$ where $Y$ is Binomial(n,p)? If it is not exactly computable, then are their ways to approximate this qty?

Comment: For $L=2, N=n$, Mathematica gives an exact answer with the incomplete $\beta$ function:  $-\frac{1}{2} i (1-p)^n \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right)
   n} \left((n-1) \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^{i n}
   B_{\frac{p}{p-1}}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) n,n-1\right)-n
   \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^{i n}
   B_{\frac{p}{p-1}}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) n,n\right)-(n-1)
   B_{\frac{p}{p-1}}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) n,n-1\right)+n
   B_{\frac{p}{p-1}}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}\right) n,n\right)\right)$

Comment: Mathematica also produces results for $N\neq n$ and larger values of $L$, albeit more complicated ones.

Comment: When Mathematica produces answers like this, it often seems to be a restatement of the problem, and not really progress. Does this expression help if you want to approximate the value?

Comment: @DouglasZare, it does help for some purposes.  The answer from Maple is more readable and understandable, but for large $n$ (and $L=2$), this will give you the answer more quickly and with better precision.

Answer (score -5):

It is exactly calculated in Maple by
$$with(Statistics):
Y := RandomVariable(Binomial(n, p)):
 $$ $$ M := Mean(Y^L/(Y^L+(N-Y)^L))\,assuming\, N::posint, L::posint$$ which produces $$\sum _{{\it \_t0}=0}^{n}{\frac {{{\it \_t0}}^{L}{n\choose {\it \_t0}}{
p}^{{\it \_t0}} \left( 1-p \right) ^{n-{\it \_t0}}}{{{\it \_t0}}^{L}+
 \left( N-{\it \_t0} \right) ^{L}}}
 $$

Comment: This just looks like the definition of expectation. How does this help?

Comment: @ Douglas Zare : So what?